# An asp.net core web API with swagger doesn’t work in Docker in Azure

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, swashbuckle

1. I create an asp.net core web API application us VS2017, the .net core version is 1.1.
2. And then I add Docker support for the web API application
3. Run the web API in Docker in local, works fine.
4. Deploy it to Docker in Azure using vs2017, works fine in Docker in Azure.
5. Add swagger UI for the .net core web API using Swashbuckle.
6. Re-run the web API in Docker in local, works fine.
7. Re-deploy it to Docker in Azure using vs2017, it doesn’t work. It shows following error

“Network Error (tcp_error) 
A communication error occurred: ""
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time”

Then I think it may be caused by swagger and Swashbuckle, but it works fine in Docker in my local. And also, I tried to remove Swashbuckle and coding of Swagger. It still does not work.

Does anyone know what the issue maybe?

Comment: Did you use a recent Swashbuckle.AspNetCore nuget package and follow the instructions on https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore ?

Comment: Thanks so much! That’s because I am still using "Swashbuckle.6.0.0-beta*”, but it is no longer valid. Should to use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. When I followed the instructions, this issues is addressed. But encountered another issue, seems Swashbuckle.AspNetCore doesn’t support documentation when route has parameter. Since it is a different topic, so I post a new question, could you please help to look if you have time? Thank so much.
The new question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320416/does-swashbuckle-aspnetcore-support-documentation-when-route-has-parameter