# Does Swashbuckle.AspNetCore support documentation when route has parameter?

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I follow the instructions by https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

1. create a new asp.net core web api project
2. add nugget package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore
3. Add code for swagger

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
        {
            Version = "v1",
            Title = "API (version 1.0)",
            Description = "A RESTFUL API"
        });
        options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlDocPath);                
    });


app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API");
});
```

4. Add code for controller

```cs
//[Route("{abc}/v1/Values")]
[Route("v1/Values")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    /// <summary>
    /// aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // POST api/values
    /// <summary>
    /// bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }
}
```

Run it, the api service works fine, and the swagger works fine with documentation.

If I change the Route from `[Route("v1/Values")]` to `[Route("{abc}/v1/Values")]`, the api service works fine, but the swagger shows 500 error.

If I change Route from `[Route("v1/Values")]` to `[Route("{abc}/v1/Values")]` and remove the documentation, comment following code `options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlDocPath)` the api service works fine, and the swagger works fine without documentation.

Based on above, seems `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` doesn’t support documentation when route has parameter, is it true? If no, does anyone know how to address it?

Comment: What is the exception that is causing the internal server error?

Comment: That's also my question, just see a 500 error, cannot find any exception details. This is very simple POC to reproduce the exception, so if possible, you can reproduce it in you local to see, may be spend 10 minutes for you. So you can see what happen. And if you like, I can send my POC code to you.